# Zipping files in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to using `Zip` feature that .NET 4.5 has provided. I have got `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` and it has 3 overloads. All of those demands sourceDirectoryName and not filename directly. I want to zip only single file not entire folder. Putting it into folder is only option? Why can't I zip it without that?

Comment: Check 7zip.. great library for file compression.

Comment: Please note that there's no such thing as C# 4.5. C# is the *language* and doesn't have any knowledge of `ZipFile` etc - you meant .NET 4.5.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\myZip.zip",FileMode.Create))
using (ZipArchive za = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    za.CreateEntryFromFile(@"C:\Temp\myFile.txt", "myFile.txt");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. What is ZipArchive?

Comment: @Imad:- It is a class. Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx): `Represents a package of compressed files in the zip archive format.`

Comment: File is created on server hard disk, how can I download it?

Comment: @Imad:- That is a seperate question. You can ask it by posting a new question with your attempt.